# Show only one block with jquery and hide other block when user click another block or second click happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

This is a Form. When user Click the edit then the input will show. And when he/she click the save/ cancel button it would hide.

And when user click one block and do not close the one block by save or cancel and click another block then all open block will hide.

Its similar to facebook settings page. when user can open only one edit block.

[image] **FaceBook Settings Page**

I have tried with the following script (JSfiddle) but I could not get my expected result.

Here is my JS [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadsharif/3qybdcsy/)

```
<form class="skylarkForm userInfoEdit" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Display Name</td>
            <td class="displayInfoTd"> <span id="fname_span"> Ahmad </span>

            </td>
            <td class="editInfoTd">
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="Ahmad">
                <ul class="margin-top-10">
                    <li>
                        <button type="button" id="fname_save" name="fname_save" class="skylarkSmallBtn saveTrigger"><i class="fa fa-check font-size-10"></i> Save</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" class="skylarkSmallBtn white cancelTrigger"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="triggerTd"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="editTrigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Display Name"> <i class="fa fa-pencil font-10 margin-left-10"></i> Edit </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email Address</td>
            <td class="displayInfoTd"> <span id="email_span"> Ahmad </span>

            </td>
            <td class="editInfoTd">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="Email Address">
                <ul class="margin-top-10">
                    <li>
                        <button type="button" id="email_save" name="email_save" class="skylarkSmallBtn saveTrigger"><i class="fa fa-check font-size-10"></i> Save</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="button" id="" name="" class="skylarkSmallBtn white cancelTrigger"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="triggerTd"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="editTrigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Change email address"> <i class="fa fa-pencil font-10 margin-left-10"></i>Edit </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td class="displayInfoTd"> <span id="pass_span" class="font-24 no-line-height"> . . . . . . . . </span>

            </td>
            <td class="editInfoTd">
                <input type="password" name="cur_password" id="cur_password" placeholder="Current password">
                <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" placeholder="New password">
                <input type="password" name="confirm_new_password" id="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Repeat new password">
                <ul class="margin-top-10">
                    <li>
                        <button type="button" id="password_save" name="password_save" class="skylarkSmallBtn saveTrigger"><i class="fa fa-check font-size-10"></i> Save</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" class="skylarkSmallBtn white cancelTrigger"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="triggerTd"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="editTrigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Change password"> <i class="fa fa-pencil font-10 margin-left-10"></i> Edit</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<!-- End Form -->
```

And the scripts is

```
 ![$(function () {
     $('.editInfoTd').hide();
     $('a.editTrigger').click(function (event) {
         $(this).parent('td.triggerTd').siblings('td.displayInfoTd').hide(10);
         $(this).parent('td.triggerTd').siblings('.editInfoTd').show(10);
     });

     $('.saveTrigger').click(function (event) {
         $(this).closest('td.editInfoTd').hide(10);
         $(this).closest('td.editInfoTd').siblings('td.displayInfoTd').show(10);
     });


     $('.cancelTrigger').click(function (event) {
         $(this).closest('td.editInfoTd').hide(10);
         $(this).closest('td.editInfoTd').siblings('td.displayInfoTd').show(10);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to edit your html. First I removed all the unrelated attributes and clases.

Then I separated the columns of each section in two rows. The first row, with class information, is what is shown when the section is closed.

The second row, contains the inputs, and is shown when you click edit.

```
    <tr class="information">
        <td>Display Name</td>
        <td>Ahmad</td>
        <td>
            <a class="editTrigger" href="#">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="detail">
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="Ahmad" />
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="saveTrigger">Save</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="cancelTrigger">Cancel</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

After that, it was a matter of show or hide entire rows. First I have a function to reset the table to the initial state.

```
function resetState() {
    $(".detail").hide();                     // close all details
    $(".information").show();                // show all headers
};
```

and then, on each button, I show or hide the corresponding rows.

```
$(".editTrigger").click(function() {
    resetState();
    $(this).parents("tr").hide();            // hide current header
    $(this).parents("tr").next("tr").show(); // show current detail
});

$(".cancelTrigger").click(function() {
    resetState();
});
```

You can see [my version of your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3qybdcsy/1/)

I hope this is what you are looking for.